# Remove object from array in document MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I'm using NextJS with MongoDB.
My DB contains two collections Events and Users. A user looks like this:

```
"_id": {
    "$oid": "659c53e3cd9f958dcc3433c0"
  },
  "username": "user1",
  "email": "user1@gmail.com",
  "hostingEvents": [
    {
      "$oid": "65aaab34277e0f044566eef2"
    },
    {
      "$oid": "65aedf5201f7cdf66482fb82"
    }
    {
  ],
  "userCreatedAt": {
    "$date": "2024-01-08T19:58:27.249Z"
  },
  "__v": 2
}
```

I want to delete the DB entry both from `Events` and from the users `hostingEvents` array. There is no problem deleting it from `Events` but I can't seem to delete it from `hostingEvents`. I'm sending the event's id as params in the URL. (http://localhost:3000/api/events/65aedf5201f7cdf66482fb82)

```
export const DELETE = async (_, { params }) => {
  const session = {
    user: {
      name: 'user1',
      email: 'user1@gmail.com',
      id: '659c53e3cd9f958dcc3433c0',
    },
    expires: '2024-02-21T18:34:45.304Z',
  };

  if (!session) {
    return new Response('Please log in', { status: 401 });
  }

  try {
    await connectToDB();
    const deletedEvent = await Event.findByIdAndDelete(params.id);

    if (deletedEvent) {
      try {
        const user = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
          { _id: session.user.id },
          { $pull: { hostingEvents: { _id: params.id } } },
          { new: true }
        );

        return new Response('Event deleted', { status: 200 });
        
      } catch (error) {
        return new Response('Could not delete event', { status: 500 });
      }
    } else {
      return new Response('Could not find event', { status: 404 });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return new Response('Error deleting event', { status: 500 });
  }
};
```

I have tried `{ $pull: { hostingEvents: { _id: ObjectId(params.id) } } }` as well with the same result.

Comment: You should just do `{ $pull: { hostingEvents: params.id } }`, as your array contains just ObjectIds, not objects. See [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PlNM0OHTIk7)

Comment: This gave me the same result as before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `param.id` is a string so `hostingEvents: { _id: params.id }` doesn't match anything. Change it to:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


const user = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
   { _id: session.user.id },
   { $pull: { hostingEvents: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(params.id)} },
   { new: true }
);
```

Comment: This gave me the same result as before.

Comment: @Elin i read again. use `{ $pull: { hostingEvents: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(params.id)} }` . Dont have `_id` to query in `hostingEvents`

Comment: I'll updated the answer

Comment: Thanks. Also adding `new` before `mongoose.Types.ObjectId(params.id)` solved it.